# asp:HyperLink populating {0}

Tags: asp.net

I have the following HyperLink:

```
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/pros.aspx?proid={0}"  Text=<%#CObj(Eval("ProID"))%>  DataNavigateUrlFields=<%#CObj(Eval("ProID"))%> />
```

The result is that I get a hyperlink that shows the current ID

```
 9855555
```

but when I hover over it, it shows the following url:

```
    http://localhost/CDDDev/pros.aspx?proid={0}
```

I wanted the {0} to be populated with the actual ProID

As such, I wanted it to show something like:

```
    http://localhost/CDDDev/pros.aspx?proid=9855555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using String.format in the NavigateUrl property:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/pros.aspx?proid={0}", Eval("ProID").ToString())%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<%#CObj(Eval("ProID"))%>` from the `DataNavigateUrlFields` part. It expects a property names separated by commas if you have more than one. Just do this:

```
DataNavigateUrlFields="ProID"
```

Multiple Properties example:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/pros.aspx?proid={0}&catid={1}"  DataNavigateUrlFields="ProID,CatID"
```